# Solving the system but are equal to variables

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I solve this system?

$ 4x + 3y = a $

$ -5x - 4y = b $

Comment: Same methods work add in the case when $a$ and $b$ are numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying first equation by $5$ and second by $4$ we get
$$
20 x + 15 y = 5a \\
-20 x -16y = 4b.
$$
Suming these equations we get $x$ vanished and $-y = 5a + 4b$, thus $y = -5a - 4b$. Substituting this into first (or second) equation we get $x = 4a + 3b$.

Comment: oh i see, wow this is very easy